# How to insert data from ASP.net textbox to two different table on single button click event?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using this code to insert into a single table.

How to use the code to insert the textbox text to multiple tables of same column on single button click event in VB.net?

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Protected Sub ImageButton1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles ImageButton1.Click
        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO a1_ticket (seat_remain) VALUES('" & Trim(Label1.Text) & "')"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


        con.Close()

    End Sub
```

Comment: There is no need to shout. All caps means online shouting. Or check that the caps lock is set to off (*little lite must be off*).

Comment: The small h in the title is a definite indicator of caps lock.

Comment: Removed the shouting due to my eyes...it bleeds!

Answer (score 1):

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
```

I use this, only make the code run.

```
%@ Page Language="VB" %> 

<!DOCTYPE html...
```

Thanks also to the first poster :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to use parameterised queries, beware of SQL Injection attacks.

You can execute two or more sql statements with one command, just concatenate them :

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO a1_ticket (seat_remain) VALUES(@seat_remain); ";
sql += "INSERT INTO a2_ticket (seat_remain) VALUES(@seat_remain);";
cmd.CommandText = sql;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@seat_remain", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
cmd.Parameters["@seat_remain"].Value = Label1.Text;
```

Comment: CAN U PLZ MODIFY MY CODE ABOVE TO DO THAT ?